# Groupby and Sample pandas

Tags: python, pandas, random, pandas-groupby

I am trying to sample the resulting data after doing a groupby on multiple columns. If the respective groupby has more than 2 elements, I want to take sample 2 records, else take all the records

df:

```
col1   col2   col3   col4
A1     A2     A3     A4
A1     A2     A3     A5
A1     A2     A3     A6
B1     B2     B3     B4
B1     B2     B3     B5
C1     C2     C3     C4
```

target df:

```
col1   col2   col3   col4
A1     A2     A3     A4 or A5 or A6
A1     A2     A3     A4 or A5 or A6
B1     B2     B3     B4
B1     B2     B3     B5
C1     C2     C3     C4
```

I have mentioned A4 or A5 or A6 because, when we take sample, either of the three might return

This is what i have tried so far:

```
trial = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['col1', 'col2','col3'])['col4'].apply(lambda x: x if (len(x) <=2) else x.sample(2)))
```

However, in this I do not get col1, col2 and col3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need double [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) - first for remove `3.rd` level of `MultiIndex` and second for convert `MultiIndex` to columns:

```
trial= (df.groupby(['col1', 'col2','col3'])['col4']
        .apply(lambda x: x if (len(x) <=2) else x.sample(2))
        .reset_index(level=3, drop=True)
        .reset_index())
```

Or [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with `drop` for remove column `level_3`:

```
trial= (df.groupby(['col1', 'col2','col3'])['col4']
        .apply(lambda x: x if (len(x) <=2) else x.sample(2))
        .reset_index()
        .drop('level_3', 1))

print (trial)
  col1 col2 col3 col4
0   A1   A2   A3   A4
1   A1   A2   A3   A6
2   B1   B2   B3   B4
3   B1   B2   B3   B5
4   C1   C2   C3   C4
```

Comment: Thank you, I am able to run this on the sample dataframe that i provided absolutely fine, but when i run the same on slice of another dataframe, it gives me only the numeric index. I tried resetting index for the parent dataframe,  but i still get the same

Comment: Data are same? What return `print (df.info)` ?

Comment: <bound method DataFrame.info of index col1 col2 col3 col4

Comment: Sorry, I forget `()` - `print (df.info()) `

Comment: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 10 entries, 0 to 9
Data columns (total 5 columns):
index    10 non-null int64
col1      10 non-null object
col2     10 non-null object
col3    10 non-null object
col4      10 non-null object
dtypes: int64(1), object(4)
memory usage: 560.0+ bytes
None

Comment: @msksantosh - So this dataframe failed for you? Is possible show data? print (df.to_dict('list')) ?

Comment: {'col1': ['H1', 'H1', 'H2', 'H2', 'H2', 'H2', 'H1', 'H2', 'H2', 'H1'], 'col4': ['ANC', 'BRK', 'TRF', 'LMR', 'NPQ', 'ARG', 'MCK', 'NOR', 'MJL', 'TFG'], 'col2': ['ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'XYZ', 'XYZ', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'XYZ'], 'col3': ['8888M', '8888M', '8888M', '8888M', '8888M', '8888M', '8888M', '8888M', '8888M', '8888M']}

Comment: I test this data and for me working nice, for you failed?

Comment: yes, the only difference i see is the different index. Will that cause any problem? My dataset has different index and the dataframe that you created from my df.to_dict('list') will have sequential index

Comment: Hmmm, It is weird. You datafarme is different as `df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['H1', 'H1', 'H2', 'H2', 'H2', 'H2', 'H1', 'H2', 'H2', 'H1'], 'col4': ['ANC', 'BRK', 'TRF', 'LMR', 'NPQ', 'ARG', 'MCK', 'NOR', 'MJL', 'TFG'], 'col2': ['ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'XYZ', 'XYZ', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'XYZ'], 'col3': ['8888M', '8888M', '8888M', '8888M', '8888M', '8888M', '8888M', '8888M', '8888M', '8888M']})` ?

Comment: No, they are the same just the index are different and the order of columns is different.

Comment: Hmmm, what is your pandas version?

Comment: Pandas version - '0.19.2'

Comment: @msksantosh - Is possible upgrade?

Comment: Yes, i upgraded it and it works fine now, Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @msksantosh - Glad can help!

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to convert this to a pandas dataframe its one by default

```
trial=df.groupby(['col1', 'col2','col3'])['col4'].apply(lambda x: x if (len(x) <=2) else x.sample(2))
```

And this should add the col1,2,3

```
trial.reset_index(inplace=True,drop=False)
```

Comment: I get this error:   TypeError: Cannot reset_index inplace on a Series to create a DataFrame